# Why doesn't GRUB2 menu appear? (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 dual-boot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have been struggling with the following issue for a while:

I have installed **Ubuntu** **16.04** in **dual-boot** with **Windows 10 (x64 version)** on my **HP laptop**
equipped with a **UEFI** instead of a good-old BIOS, and **I can't seem to access the GRUB2 menu** from which I can launch either Ubuntu or Windows 10.

The boot process is always hijacked by the Windows Boot Manager.

**I've tried many solutions** after reading so many similar questions on different forums and in different tutorials.

1- I **turned off Windows 10's fast-startup** feature.

2- I **changed the boot order** using an elevated command line in **Windows 10**:

- While keeping **secure boot enabled** : `bcedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`
- While **disabling secure boot** from the UEFI settings : `bcedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

3- I've tried accessing Ubuntu in LiveCD mode from a bootable USB and used the utility "boot-repair" to repair the boot-order and ended up with having an error:

> an error occurred during the repair.
>
> Please write on a paper the following URL: http://paste2.org/WXMwaeOv
>
> In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to: boot.repair@gmail.com
>
> You can now reboot your computer. Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sdb (1000 GB) disk!
>
> If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your BIOS. If your BIOS does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader. For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt: `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`

Thank you very much ahead for your help and effort!!

Comment: When I had a pc with UEFI boot, I was able to mount my EFI partition and make some edits to enable a boot menu to appear and allow me to select the bootloader I wanted to use on every boot. I don't know if this was manufacturer-specific or not, a quick google search turns up nothing. Does your bios allow you to set whether ubuntu bootloader or windows bootloader starts first? My current bios allows me to change the boot order of bootloaders.

Comment: Did you do as boot-repair suggested?